# NHibernate asks hibernate.cfg.xml even if web.config configured

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5, nhibernate-mapping

this is ASP.NET MVC 5 Sample App.
trying to learn MVC's module NHibernate.

if I understand right. hibernate.cfg.xml file is not neccessary if settings coded in web.config as a configsection.

is xmlns version is wrong ? or do you see something misspelled ?
so why NHibernate asks hibernate.cfg.xml even if web.config configured?
(thanks)

```
<configSections>
<section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate" />
...

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-version-2.2">
    <session-factory>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string_name">LocalMySqlServer</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

getting this error:

```
Could not find file '...\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\bin\Debug\hibernate.cfg.xml'.
```

and DB Class static member (which used once in global.asax.cs Application_Start method) is:

```
public static void Configure()
    {

        var config = new Configuration();
        config.Configure();


        var mapper1 = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.AddMapping<UserMap>();
        config.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
        _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

// _session factory is a class member defined as 
// private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    }
```

NHibernate 4.0.3.4000 installed [using nuget]

Comment: Try naming the element `hibernate-configuration` instead of `hybernate-configuration`.

Comment: modified, cleared project, rebuilded. no luck.
same error albeit misspell correction applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer. it seems scheme key is changed in new nhibernate version

changed

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-version-2.2">
```

to

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
```

fixes the problem. Im sure because I retested back the first scheme. and boM! same error throw. so xmlns string is updated.

how I found it.
opened web.config>xml in menu>Schemes [added nhibernate xsd files which you can find in your project\packages]
than autocompletion did worked in web.config and shown to me the correct schema string.